# How can I use tuples in nunit TestCases?

Tags: c#, nunit, valuetuple

I am trying to specify nUnit testCases using tuples, but I get a compiler error in VisualStudio.

This simple example demonstrates what I am trying to do:

```
    [TestCase((1, 2), (3, 5))]
    public void TestRangeOverlaps((int start, int end) firstRange, (int start, int end) secondRange)
    {

    }
```

If this is possible, what am I missing?

Comment: This is not specific to nunit, but a general restriction of Attributes: only constant values of very specific types can be used as attribute parameters (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`TestCaseSource`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestCaseSource-Attribute) attribute and specify `IEnumerable<(int, int)[]>` for value source.

Every `IEnumerable` item represents a set of parameters passed to test method. In your case it's a two tuples, so you should return an array of them every time to pass to `TestRangeOverlaps`

```cs
[Test]
[TestCaseSource(nameof(Tuples))]
public void TestRangeOverlaps((int start, int end) firstRange, (int start, int end) secondRange)
{
}

public static IEnumerable<(int, int)[]> Tuples
{
    get
    {
        yield return new[] { (1, 2), (3, 5) };
    }
}
```

`TestCase` attribute supports only constant values