# How to use tuple with TestCasesSource in NUnit?

Tags: c#, testing, nunit, valuetuple, testcasesource

I've been writing some tests in **C#** using **NUnit** unitl I encountered an issue with test where I'd like to pass **2 times a 3 Item Tuples** as an argument to the test.
Seems like a similar problem as described here: [How can I use tuples in nunit TestCases?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910839/how-can-i-use-tuples-in-nunit-testcases)

So I implemented the solution with introducing new static method and passing its name to the **TestCaseSource** however it doesn't seem to work fully in my case.
The only difference is I have tuples consisting of **3 Item tuple** instead of **2**.

The test passes just **partially** - it passes the **Assert.AreEqual** but somehow it  doesn't passes the whole test(weird considering the fact there is only one set of arguments?) and shows 1 test **has not been run**.

Here's the test source code:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCaseSource(nameof(TestGetTimeLeftData))]
    public void TestGetTimeLeft((int, int, int) alarmTime, (int, int, int) clockTime)
    {
        (int, int, int) expectedTime = (3, 0, 0);
        (int, int, int) result = Helper.GetTimeLeft(alarmTime, clockTime);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedTime, result);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<(int, int, int)[]> TestGetTimeLeftData
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new[] { (2, 0, 0), (23, 0, 0) };
        }
    }
```

[image: Test Explorer Window Output]

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your test takes two arguments, both `(int, int, int)`. The `yield` statement in your test case source is returning a single argument, which is an array of `(int, int, int)`. that's not the same thing.

Try returning a `TestCaseData` object instead...

```
private static IEnumerable<TestCaseData> TestGetTimeLeftData
{
    get
    {
        yield return new TestCaseData((2, 0, 0), (23, 0, 0));
    }
}
```

This can be done with an object array instead, but `TestCaseData` exists in order to make it easier to write test case sources.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to look more neat than the solution with an array of tuples. However I still have just **6/7 tests passed**. Right now I'm confused because I opened this project in **Rider** and there are only 6 test instead of 7. I know my quirk but I can't grasp why there is an additional test in VS.

Comment: I don't understand. Your example shows 2 tests.